# Controller Code Organization in Angular

Tags: angularjs

So, I'm in the midst of my first major project with Angular. I have one controller that is doing a *ton* of the legwork, and it's reached the point where it's thousands of lines of JavaScript.

I'd like to break this up somehow, but I can't seem to find a solid example anywhere. The code is mostly made up of functions used to do calculations on objects, so directives and modules don't seem like the right answer, but I could be wrong there.

How are you guys organizing code in your large Angular projects? Should I just suck it up, or is there a sane way to split this into easy to scan files?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suggest putting at least some of those objects and their related calculations into services, then inject the services into your controller(s).  See the [Sticky Notes Part 1 blog entry](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-1-architecture/) for an example of a service that encapsulates some data and provides methods to access/manipulate that data.

See if you can break up your controller into multiple controllers, one for each view.  A view can be as large as a page, or just some chunk/block on a page.

To quote from a google group post I saw recently: "I prefer to think of angular controllers as dumb apis/configs for my views and leave all the heavy lifting to services." -- [reference](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/eegk_lB6kVs/rCvY4K3ih0AJ)

Comment: Just sharing, this might giving you some ideas. [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987001/loading-partial-page-with-angular-and-compile-the-controller)

Comment: I am literally passing the $scope variable from the controller to services, and it works great, because in the service we reference $scope.x, but it seems ugly and nobody on my team including myself is especially in love with the pattern :/

Answer (score 23):

There are a few things that you need to ask yourself when you are in a controller.

1. Are you doing any DOM manipulation in the controller? This is a definite NO. Dont ever do that. It always belongs in the directives department.
2. Are you writing any Business Logic in your controller? That too is a NO. Your Business logic should in most cases exist in a Service. That is the right place for it.

Now, have a look at your controller. Is it devoid of these 2 things and still larger than 1000 lines? It is highly unlikely, but even if it somehow is happening, then consider breaking down your controller into smaller controllers. This breaking of controllers have to be done based on the view.

To sum things up, your controller is just a place where you glue up the business logic and your views in the HTML. It should technically never contain anything other than these glues.

Comment: +1 The AngularJS docs state that the controller should "contain only the business logic needed for a single view", http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller. But I've found that as soon as some data needs to be shared between two controllers or two views, it is best to put the data (and methods that manipulate it) into a service.  So, I think I like your recommendation better -- put the business logic into services  to start with, then you're ready if/when multiple views or controllers need it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a Util factory (seems to be the way to go now in Angular rather than services) and have it return any shared logic as a set of methods.

https://gist.github.com/lamba/c275f5f010090632209e