# Why does not load files CSS/JS in ng-view Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use `$routeProvider` and load views HTML via `<div ng-view></div>`.
In loaded file HTML there is HTML:

```
<script src="/public/js/tags/tokenize/jquery.tokenize.js"></script>
<link href="/public/js/tags/tokenize/jquery.tokenize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But these files are not connected in page. Also JS does not exicute on `ng-view`

Comment: Have you added something like  <script src="resources/vendors/angular/angular.min.js" /> into your html file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Angular thinks your `<script>` is the directive [script](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script). You have two possible solutions:

- create a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- include your code out of the app.

If you need to dinamically load your resources use a *service*, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695156/angular-js-load-css-and-js-files-dynamically).

Also, for reference, take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050706/javascript-inside-script-tag-in-an-angularjs-template-is-not-executed) too